# How to remove the Calculator app from AOSP build

Tags: android, build

Currently, I'm working on Quectel SC20 EVB and build the google android 8.1 source code for the same. After successfully build the code I reprogram the SC20 module and it runs on the android 8.1 with my build date and time.

Next, I try to remove some unwanted apps from the build source. For example, I consider the Calculator app that needs to remove. I use the command "find . -name *.mk | xargs grep "Calculator"" to search the existence of Calculator in LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME and related macros.

Here is the response of find command

```
./build/make/target/product/core.mk:    ExactCalculator \
./vendor/qcom/proprietary/qrdplus/China/ChinaMobile/products.mk:    CmccCalculatorRes \
./vendor/qcom/proprietary/qrdplus/China/ChinaMobile/res/Calculator/Android.mk:LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := CmccCalculatorRes
./platform_testing/tests/functional/calculator/Android.mk:LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := CalculatorFunctionalTests
./device/qcom/common/base.mk:    Calculator \
./device/generic/goldfish-opengl/shared/OpenglCodecCommon/Android.mk:        ChecksumCalculator.cpp \
./art/oatdump/Android.mk:.PHONY: dump-oat-Calculator
./art/oatdump/Android.mk:dump-oat-Calculator: $(TARGET_OUT_APPS)/Calculator.odex $(DEFAULT_DEX_PREOPT_BUILT_IMAGE) $(OATDUMP)
./art/oatdump/Android.mk:   $(OATDUMP) --oat-file=$< --output=$(ART_DUMP_OAT_PATH)/Calculator.oatdump.txt
./art/oatdump/Android.mk:   @echo Output in $(ART_DUMP_OAT_PATH)/Calculator.oatdump.txt
./packages/apps/ExactCalculator/Android.mk:LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := packages/apps/ExactCalculator/res
./packages/apps/ExactCalculator/Android.mk:LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := ExactCalculator
./packages/apps/ExactCalculator/Android.mk:LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Calculator
```

I comment the ExactCalculator from

```
./build/make/target/product/core.mk
./device/qcom/common/base.mk
```

and add **ifeq (0,1)** and **endif** in

```
./packages/apps/ExactCalculator/Android.mk
```

to disable the Calculator portion.

Next use the **make installclean** to clean the old image files and the **make** to build the new changes.

I use QFIL tool to program the SC20 module, the same as I used all the time to program the same module. But the calculator still presents after the new start.

I also use the fastboot method to manually flash the **.img** files to the EVB but does not change anything.

Can anyone help me out...

Comment: Did you figure this out? What does your device.mk file look like? Is the source code for your ROM / manifest.xml public?